# Key 'Alt Gr' is disabled and replaced by 'Alt'

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard

I have accidentally pressed some keyboard shortcut which caused the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key to be replaced by plain <kbd>Alt</kbd> key behavior. However, I don't know which shortcut it was, even after trying a lot of different combinations. After restarting my PC, the problem is solved, but I fell into this situation a few times now, and it is really inconvenient.

How do I configure the behavior of the right alt key?

Note: I'm working on a Windows Vista machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Key Tweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/).

[image]

Comment: Looks good, and very user friendly. I am using AutoHotkey for this purpose. It is more difficult to use, but very flexible.

Comment: Keytweak is awesome.

I used it to fix the layout of my mac keyboard on a windows computer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Vista, but on XP the default key combination to switch between different locales is `<Left-shift>` and `<Left-Alt>` (hold one key while pressing the other).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this was the solution, but I can't reproduce the problem anymore.

Comment: I had this problem, so I tested this solution and it didn't work :(